# RegEx to find a pattern and replace with altered result

Tags: regex, notepad++, find-replace

I cannot seem to find an exact answer with explanation, but I have a very simple Regular Expression (Find and Replace in Notepad++) I am trying to build but cannot seem to get it to work.

I have the string :

> x1 expression x2 x-ray x3 rex x4 xylophone

and want to alter if to be :

> $1 expression $2 x-ray $3 rex $4 xylophone

I can fine the patterns I am changing by using `x[0-9]` , but I cannot get it to replace the x*number* with the $*number*.

I tried `\$$0` but the replacement ends up as follows:

> $x1 expression $x2 x-ray $x3 rex $x4 xylophone

Please help with explanation of how I can only extract the number from the string that is found.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
x(\d)
```

and replace with `\$$1`. Or, to make sure you are maching whole words, add a word boundary `\b` before `x`:

```
\bx(\d)
^^
```

The `\bx(\d)` expression matches `x`, then matches and captures a digit into Group 1. The replacement is a literal `$` char (that is defined with `\$` as `$` is special in the string replacement pattern) and the backreference to the Group 1 value, `$1`.

[image]

Note that the following replacement patterns seem to work, too:

```
$\1
$$$1
```

Comment: You may also want to check [Boost replacement strings syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).